# NSDateFormatter returning nil NSDate object

Tags: iphone

```
NSDateFormatter *aDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[aDateFormatter setLocale:aLocale];
[aDateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[aDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM dd, yyyy"];
NSDate *aDateFromString = [aDateFormatter dateFromString:aKey];
```

Here,
aKey = lun, October 11, 2010
aLocale = fr_CH

My `aDateFromString` is coming as `nil`. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Use the buttons or indent with 4 spaces for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around with this for a bit, and this code below gets a legit NSDate:

```
NSString *df = @"EEE, MMM dd, yyyy";
NSString *ds = @"lun., Octobre 11, 2010";
NSLocale *aLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_CH"];

NSDateFormatter *aDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[aDateFormatter setLocale:aLocale];
[aDateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[aDateFormatter setDateFormat:df];
NSDate *aDateFromString = [aDateFormatter dateFromString:ds];
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things to look at:

- use MMMM (four Ms) instead of MMM if the string contains the full month name
- in fr_CH, MMMM for October is "octobre" ("re" not "er")
- in fr_CH, EEE for Monday is "lun." (period at end)

Make sure aKey is in the proper format and correct the DateFormat string.

Comment: I think you are right. In my aKey I am getting "lun,Oct 11, 2010". So you mean to say I should change it to "lun.,octobre 11, 2010"? and add one more M in date formatter?

Comment: Yes, aKey needs to be in that format if you want the date formatter to interpret it correctly.  If possible, get date strings as yyyy-MM-dd to avoid spelling issues.